# $match = TRUE - not working to reduce block visibility in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

Trying to show a block for Drupal only under certain conditions - I tried to write out something that would allow a `$match = TRUE` in the event that the content type is an article OR it was one of the archive pages (format `/archive-monthname`) or the news page (`/news`).

For some reason, it is not showing on any of the pages desired.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$match = FALSE;
$types = array('article' => 1);
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  $nid = arg(1);
  $node = node_load($nid);
  $type = $node->type;
  if (isset($types[$type])) {
    $match = TRUE;
  }
}


switch (substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 0) {

case "/archive-january":
$match = TRUE;
break;
case "/archive-february":
$match = TRUE;
break;
case "/archive-march":
$match = TRUE;
break;
case "/archive-april":
$match = TRUE;
break;
case "/archive-may":
$match = TRUE;
break;
case "/archive-june":
$match = TRUE;
break;
case "/archive-july":
$match = TRUE;
break;
case "/archive-august":
$match = TRUE;
break;
case "/archive-september":
$match = TRUE;
break;
case "/archive-october":
$match = TRUE;
break;
case "/archive-november":
$match = TRUE;
break;
case "/archive-december":
$match = TRUE;
break;
case "/news":
$match = TRUE;
break;
}
return $match;
?>
```

Comment: you don't need to duplicate `$match = TRUE;` in each `case`. just wtite all your cases and then `$match = TRUE;break;` once.

Answer (score 0):

Here: `switch(substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 0) {`, you are missing a closing bracket.

Might be one of the problems.

---

Also, `substr(ANYTHING, 0)` just returns this ANYTHING, so I think it's kinda pointless.